# angular-dialog-service update parent scope data object

Tags: angularjs

I've a template:

```
<p class="text-right">
    <a ng-click="editTherapeuticProposal(meow.accepted_tp)" class="fa fa-pencil"></a>
</p>
```

which calls the editTherapeuticProposal function defined in its controller, passing it the `meow.accepted_tp` object  (here I use angular-dialog-service: https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service):

```
// here tp is equal to meow.accepted_tp
$scope.editTherapeuticProposal = function(tp) {
    dialogs.create('surgeon/templates/create_edit_therapeutic_proposal.tpl.html', 'SurgeonCreateEditTherapeuticProposalCtrl', {scope: $scope, tp: tp}, { copy: false });
};
```

tp is an object.

Then in the dialog controller I display a form in order to let the user modify tp. I do some stuff, the relevant ones are:

```
// data is the object received by the dialog controller: {scope: $scope, tp: tp}
if(typeof data.tp != 'undefined') {
   $scope.therapeuticProposal = angular.copy(data.tp);
}
```

I copy the object to work on a different object (I don't want data to be updated if not saved)

When pressing the save button in the dialog, the following function runs:

```
var complete = function(tp) {
  data.tp = tp;
  //...
}
```

Ok, the problem is that `meow.accepted_tp` in the parent scope doesn't get updated. If I do

```
var complete = function(tp) {
  data.tp.title = 'meow';
  //...
}
```

Its title gets updated. There is clearly something wrong with the prototypal inheritance, I know that in order to get variables updated they should be properties of an object, but tp is already passed as an object property (of the data object). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
After re-reading the angular-dialog-service docs, you can pass a result back using modalInstance. It sounds like this is what you want to do.
The reason your binding isn't working is because you're changing the object reference from a child scope, rather than a property on the object bound (which is why data.tp.title = 'meow' works).

Anyway, for your case, try this:

```
// here tp is equal to meow.accepted_tp
$scope.editTherapeuticProposal = function(tp) {
    var dlg = dialogs.create('surgeon/templates/create_edit_therapeutic_proposal.tpl.html', 'SurgeonCreateEditTherapeuticProposalCtrl', {scope: $scope, data: data}, { copy: false });
    dlg.result.then(function(tp) {
         // Get the result and update meow.accept_tp
        $scope.meow.accepted_tp = tp;
    });
};
```

Then in the dialog, when you complete, do:

```
var complete = function(tp) {
  $modalInstance.close(tp);
}
```

For an example, see http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/rkIqv, in particular the customDialogCtrl (not customDialogCtrl2) is what you want.

Comment: well, I cant' do `data.accepted_tp = tp` because such form controller is a generic one and should be able to save all kinds of tps, not only the accepted one. This is the reason why I pass the tp object (no need to do that if I know the parent property by name). 
the `data` of `data.tp` is the object I pass to the dialog controller: `{scope: $scope, tp: tp}`

Comment: I've edited the question changing some variable names that could confuse you. Thanks for your answer.